# How do I override some functions in the Queue STL object?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am trying to override the push and pop functions from the STL queue.  I think I need to use templates.  I get a 'MyQueue' does not name a type (this error is in my main.cpp file) and an error saying expected initializer before '<' token.  Here is the snippet of code:

```
#include "MyQueue.h"

sem_t EmptySem;
sem_t PresentSem;
sem_t mutex;

MyQueue::MyQueue()
{
    sem_init(&EmptySem, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED, QSIZE);
    sem_init(&PresentSem, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED, 0);
    sem_init(&mutex, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED, 1);
}

template <class Elem>
void queue<Elem>::push(const Elem &Item)
{
    sem_wait(EmptySem);
    sem_wait(mutex);
    super.push(Item);
    sem_post(mutex);
    sem_post(PresentSem);
} 
template <class Elem>
Elem queue<Elem>::pop(void)
{
    Elem item;
    sem_wait(PresentSem);
    sem_wait(mutex);
    item = super.front();
    super.pop();
    signal(mutex);
    signal(EmptySem);
    return item;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override functions that are not defined as virtual. So you gain nothing by publicly inheriting from std::queue.

It would be best if `MyQueue` stored a member that was a `std::queue`. That way, you can do whatever you want and just forward the functions to the `std::queue` member.

Also, C++ has no keyword `super`; that's Java.